# Drawing a transparent circle in center of an arc in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

i would like to draw a hole at the middle of an arc like a disk
I tried to draw an transparent circle inside an arc to make a hole
i tried this

```
enter code here
 public ClassBlade(Context context, float Width) : base(context)
    {
       diameter = Width;
        eraser.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));
        eraser.AntiAlias = true;
        bm = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)diameter/2, (int)diameter/2, Bitmap.Config.Alpha8);
    }
    private void drawblade()
    {
        bm.EraseColor(Color.Transparent);
        thepaint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.DarkOrange;
         thecanvas.DrawArc(0, 0, diameter, diameter, 0, 120, true, thepaint);
          thepaint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Indigo;
          thecanvas.DrawArc(0, 0, diameter, diameter, 120, 120, true,thepaint);
           thepaint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.DarkCyan;
           thecanvas.DrawArc(0, 0, diameter, diameter,240, 120, true, thepaint);
           cv.DrawCircle(0, diameter / 2, diameter / 2, eraser);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried and how for us to help you further